# Switch frames after login

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, tkinter, frames

I'm trying to switch to a new frame after entering the correct login and password. 
Unfortunately, nothing happens once I enter all the details.
Not sure how to force it to open that new frame. 
I ok with switching between frames without the login bit but do not know  to attach that login function to it

```
 from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(LoginFrame)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)


        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)



        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)



    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)

        if username == "abc" and password == "123":
            lambda: parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username or password")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text="Return to login page",
                  command=lambda: parent.switch_frame(LoginFrame)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Replace `lambda: parent.switch_frame(PageOne)` with `parent.switch_frame(PageOne)`

Comment: Just tried that says:
line 51, in _login_btn_clicked
    parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
NameError: name 'parent' is not defined

Comment: ***NameError: name 'parent' is not defined"***: You have make `parent` a class method. In `__init__` do `self.parent = parent`, in `def _login_btn_clicked(...` do `self.parent.switch(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems. The root problem is these two lines of code:

```
if username == "abc" and password == "123":
    lambda: parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
```

This doesn't cause the page to switch. Instead, it's simply creating an anonymous function which would cause the page to switch. You don't want to create a function, you want to actually switch the frame. In this case it should look like this:

```
if username == "abc" and password == "123":
    parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
```

However, `parent` isn't defined. You need to save `parent` in the `__init__` method so that you can access it here.

```
class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        ...

    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        ...
        if username == "abc" and password == "123":
            self.parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

Works like a dream thanks everyone for help, pasted fixed code below

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(LoginFrame)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class LoginFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent


        self.label_username = Label(self, text="Username")
        self.label_password = Label(self, text="Password")

        self.entry_username = Entry(self)
        self.entry_password = Entry(self, show="*")

        self.label_username.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.label_password.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=1, column=1)



        self.logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command=self._login_btn_clicked)
        self.logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)



    def _login_btn_clicked(self):
        # print("Clicked")
        username = self.entry_username.get()
        password = self.entry_password.get()

        # print(username, password)

        if username == "abc" and password == "123":
            self.parent.switch_frame(PageOne)
        else:
            tm.showerror("Login error", "Incorrect username or password")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="This is page one").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text="Return to login page",
                  command=lambda: parent.switch_frame(LoginFrame)).pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```